# Send payload json on MQTT Android

Tags: android, json, mqtt, send

I want to send the data to mqtt broker using Android, but how to send the JSON format in Android?

```
public void pub (View v){
        String topic = topicstr;
        String message = "payload here";

        try {

            client.publish(topic, message.getBytes(), 0, false);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

this is the payload

```
{
  "m2m:rqp": {
    "fr": "your-access-key",
    "to": "/antares-cse/antares-id/your-application-name/your-device-name",
   "op": 1,
   "rqi": 123456,
   "pc": {
     "m2m:cin": {
       "cnf": "message",
        "con": "{\"your-first-data\":the-integer-value,\"your-second-data\":\"the-string-data\"}"
      }
    },
    "ty": 4
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what when wrong when you did?